# Conversion between primary colours

Tags: image-processing, homework

Heads up, this is homework.  Just a little stumped :)

I have some arbitrary primaries, `A`, `B`, `C`, which I want to express in terms of the standard `XYZ` primaries.

I have that the tristimulus values with respect to the `ABC` primaries for some random colour `R` is defined by some linear matrix equation:

$\begin{bmatrix} R_a \\
R_b \\
R_ c \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
= 
%
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} \\
a_{10} & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{20} & a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
R_x \\
R_y \\
R_z
\end{bmatrix}
$

How can the primaries be computed from this information?

Comment: Is your matrix non-singular?

Comment: @hotpaw2 Yes it is

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you have and what you're trying to compute.  You have the A matrix and Rxyz and are trying to compute Rabc?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I think you want to determine the [Rx,Ry,Rz] required to make the left side of your equation look like [1 0 0], [0 1 0], and [0 0 1]. This will get you A,B,C expressed in terms of X,Y,Z.